# Brunch how do you share/mixin code that changes based on where the finished app is running (app is a widget for 3rd party sites)?

Tags: brunch

I'm trying to build a widget that will be hosted on 3rd party sites.  Some of the external files it will depend on need to be pulled from different sources in different environments, i.e. in development, it should pull some files from localhost, in staging it should pull them from staging-domain.com, and in production, it should pull them from www.xyz.com

My hack solution is as follows -

in `application.coffee`:

```
prodApiHost = 'http://productionhost.com/api'

@APIHost = do ->
  if ( window.location.port.match(/^3/) || window.location.host.match(/^(localhost)/i) || window.location.host.match(/xyz.staging/i ))
    if window.location.host.match(/^(localhost)/i) || window.location.port.match(/^3/)
      window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + ':' + window.location.port + '/api'
    else
      window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/api'
  else
    prodApiHost
```

Then, in the models where I need to use that URL, I do so as follows

in `my_model.coffee`:

```
some_attribute: namespacedApp.APIHost
```

I'm *sure* there's a better way... any pointers/help greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

I found another way of doing this. I can put the same `APIHost` function in the `initialize.coffee` file like so:

```
application = require 'application'
application.prodApiHost = 'http://productionhost.com/api'

$ ->
  application.APIHost = do ->
    if ( window.location.port.match(/^3/) || window.location.host.match(/^(localhost)/i) || window.location.host.match(/xyz.staging/i ))
      if window.location.host.match(/^(localhost)/i) || window.location.port.match(/^3/)
        window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + ':' + window.location.port + '/api'
      else
        window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/api'
    else
      application.prodApiHost

application.initialize()
Backbone.history.start()
```

Now the fn is available everywhere in the app.  Still not sure this is the best solution. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd create small brunch plugin that will check if minifying is enabled (to determine production env) (`config.minify`) and make it add

```
if (window.brunch == null) window.brunch = {};
window.brunch.environment = ... (development / production)
```

and then check in your app

```
if (window.brunch.environment === 'production') {...} else {...}
```

I think separating dev / prod environments is a very common thing and in a bit brunch will receive “environments” abstraction for this purpose.